# How to import data from text file into database?

Tags: database, text

This is data in text file

## Show packet received:

dest: 8
src: 8
packnum: 4
length: 75
retry: 0
payload (HEX): 5061636B657420312C2077616E74696E6720746F20736565206966207265636569766564207061636B6574206973207468652073616D652061732073656E74207061636B6574

## payload (string): Packet 1, wanting to see if received packet is the same as sent packet

All I want to do is to store this data into database as dest,src,length,payload etc.Please let me know how to do this?

Comment: so? what have you done to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

First u should get the content from the file: [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Then extract the data from plain text.

Then you filter on what you want and put that in variables and write that to the database: [SQL Insert](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear .
No language tag has included.
But you may follow this steps :

> Extract your data from the text . in php you can do like this `<?php $data = explode(" ", "your data"); ?>`

Now you have an array with your data .

> After extracting the data into an array , you can export the array data to your database.

Comment: Thanks let me brief my question   I have data content as shown above in a text file.All i want to do is to:refine the contents so I am able to store it into a data base .Please let me know if you hav not got my point